# Plural of school subject

Tags: american-english, british-english, plural-forms

What is the plural of "school subject"? Is "school subject" also common in American English?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plural is simply:

> school subject**s**

And so far that I know, there is no other particular way to say it in American English.

Comment: At the Massachusetts Institute of Technology, a "Course" (with a capital "C") is at the level of a department or major.  A "course" (with a lower-case "c") is taught over a month or semester.  For example, a Computer Science major (in Course VI-3) usually takes four courses per semester.  The VI in "VI-3" is a roman numeral, so "VI-3" is pronounced "six three".  It is unusual to need to pluralize the capital-C Courses.  This usage of capital-C Course is peculiar to M.I.T.; it is not normal in American English.